# Autpopulate the fields on standard edit page from parent object in salesforce

Tags: standard-objects

Can someone please tell me about "Ways by which we can Autopopulate the fields on standard edit page from parent object in salesforce"
fro eg::-- i have to autopopulate "phone number" field from Account to Contact's edit page on click of new contact button on account related list..

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom button with the same structure as the standard one, just add one parameter to the url:

```
&con10={!Account.Phone}
```

To find the parameter name, right-click on the field you want to prepopulate on the contact detail page and click "Inspect Element" to find the `id` attribute in the html:

```
input id="con10" maxlength="40" name="con10" size="20" tabindex="6" type="text"
```